# How to convert JSON to data frame in R without sorting keys

Tags: r, jsonlite

Input:

```
json_string <- '{
    "Chamber": ["Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber", "Target Chamber"],
    "P1": [0.5193, 0.5409, 0.5616, 0.5589, 0.5518, 0.5527, 0.5497, 0.5535, 0.5539, 0.5549, 0.5508, 0.5538, 0.5445, 0.5512, 0.554, 0.5586, 0.5569, 0.5539, 0.5583, 0.5606, 0.5549, 0.5617, 0.5433, 0.5435, 0.5441, 0.5564, 0.5436, 0.5458, 0.5546, 0.5373, 0.533, 0.5373, 0.5399, 0.5547, 0.5601, 0.5416, 0.5497, 0.5393, 0.5595],
    "P9": [0.5155, 0.5334, 0.5599, 0.5512, 0.5456, 0.5454, 0.5466, 0.5495, 0.5471, 0.5546, 0.5437, 0.5491, 0.5424, 0.5465, 0.5495, 0.5594, 0.554, 0.5528, 0.555, 0.5518, 0.5573, 0.5596, 0.5391, 0.5553, 0.5441, 0.5597, 0.559, 0.5612, 0.5485, 0.5507, 0.5442, 0.5373, 0.545, 0.5646, 0.569, 0.5531, 0.5602, 0.5567, 0.5737],
    "P10": [0.5155, 0.5334, 0.5599, 0.5512, 0.5456, 0.5454, 0.5466, 0.5495, 0.5471, 0.5546, 0.5437, 0.5491, 0.5424, 0.5465, 0.5495, 0.5594, 0.554, 0.5528, 0.555, 0.5518, 0.5573, 0.5596, 0.5391, 0.5553, 0.5441, 0.5597, 0.559, 0.5612, 0.5485, 0.5507, 0.5442, 0.5373, 0.545, 0.5646, 0.569, 0.5531, 0.5602, 0.5567, 0.5737],
    "P11": [0.5155, 0.5334, 0.5599, 0.5512, 0.5456, 0.5454, 0.5466, 0.5495, 0.5471, 0.5546, 0.5437, 0.5491, 0.5424, 0.5465, 0.5495, 0.5594, 0.554, 0.5528, 0.555, 0.5518, 0.5573, 0.5596, 0.5391, 0.5553, 0.5441, 0.5597, 0.559, 0.5612, 0.5485, 0.5507, 0.5442, 0.5373, 0.545, 0.5646, 0.569, 0.5531, 0.5602, 0.5567, 0.5737],
    "P12": [0.5149, 0.5375, 0.5556, 0.5517, 0.5456, 0.5451, 0.5428, 0.5479, 0.5495, 0.5534, 0.5434, 0.5486, 0.5415, 0.5462, 0.5478, 0.5597, 0.5494, 0.549, 0.5464, 0.5513, 0.5561, 0.5664, 0.5432, 0.5557, 0.5482, 0.5582, 0.5537, 0.5658, 0.559, 0.546, 0.5372, 0.5378, 0.5484, 0.5612, 0.5656, 0.5495, 0.5649, 0.5638, 0.579]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you're looking for?

```
df <- data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(json_string))
head(df)
#>          Chamber     P1     P9    P10    P11    P12
#> 1 Target Chamber 0.5193 0.5155 0.5155 0.5155 0.5149
#> 2 Target Chamber 0.5409 0.5334 0.5334 0.5334 0.5375
#> 3 Target Chamber 0.5616 0.5599 0.5599 0.5599 0.5556
#> 4 Target Chamber 0.5589 0.5512 0.5512 0.5512 0.5517
#> 5 Target Chamber 0.5518 0.5456 0.5456 0.5456 0.5456
#> 6 Target Chamber 0.5527 0.5454 0.5454 0.5454 0.5451
```